# User data within RTMP/RTMPT live stream

Tags: actionscript-3, rtmp, red5

Say, I have an RTMP live stream sent to Red5 from ffmpeg. Flash client is a custom player which uses AS3 NetStream API. And I want to put some additional data to that stream on the server side, like momentary loudness. This data has to be well synced with video. And I should be able to extract that data on the Flash client side, to immediately show that data to a user.

Please, provide some tips or tutorials of how can I achieve this.

I know, FLV is not the type of container you can add extra data to. MP4 seems to be appropriate, according to [wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_container_formats). Using custom player, I tried to play an MP4 video with subtitles embedded, but on the client side NetStream client didn't receive onTextData.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To receive data within rtmp live stream, you can use `onMetaData` or `onCuePoint` events on client side.
Take a look here : http://actionscriptexamples.com/2008/02/26/loading-flv-files-in-actionscript-30-using-the-netconnection-and-netstream-classes/. Of course you should find how to send data with your live encoder.